# Adding a script to only first-level children

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get only the first-level children of a GameObject and add a script to each of the first-level children.

I am getting an error: addNavTagChildren.cs(14,21): error CS0161: 'getFirstChildren(Transform)': not all code paths return a value

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class addNavTagChildren : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        List<GameObject> childrenList = new List<GameObject>();

        //TEST

        Transform[] getFirstChildren(Transform parent)
        {
            Transform[] children = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
            Transform[] firstChildren = new Transform[parent.childCount];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (Transform child in children)
            {
                if (child.parent == parent)
                {
                    firstChildren[index] = child;
                    index++;
                    childrenList.Add(child.gameObject);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < childrenList.Count; i++)
        {
            NavMeshSourceTag nmst = childrenList[i].AddComponent<NavMeshSourceTag>();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `Transform[] getFirstChildren(Transform parent)` is a method declaration. You are telling the compiler that the method `getFirstChildren` will return an object of type `Transform[]`. However, in your method implementation, you aren't returning anything. That's what the error is complaining about. If I understand your code correctly, you probably meant to add `return firstChildren;` after the `foreach` loop?